# How to disable user Interaction on Relative layout in Android

Tags: android

I am working on android application i am using two relative layouts,I need to disable user interaction on one relative layout,i tried with layout setEnabled false,but it didn't work out,can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: You can use `setFocusable(false)` too

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in java with the method `relativeLayout.setClickable(false)` or in xml `android:clickable="false"`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what would you like to disable and what kinds of interaction are handled by that RelativeLayout and its contents.

The easiest way to turn off touches and key presses is to override dispatch* methods and provide empty implementations. It prevents all touches, keys, etc. from being passed to the children. For example to disable touches and keys:

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout{
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily **setClickable(false)** to the relative layout that you don't want to interact. Hope this help.